# Laravel 5.4 not setting a cookie in dev environment. pro environement works as expected

Tags: php, cookies, laravel-5.4

Im createing cookie as the following:

`Cookie::queue(cookie("media_source", $ms, 60 * 24 *30 ));`

this line is working in production. I see in the browser that the server requests to set the cookie and its working.
in dev, its not even asking the browser.
I can see in debug that Im reaching the line of code, but it is not sent to the browser.

`Both php 7.1 ubuntu.`
The only difference between the environment, is that the host in the dev is custom (via host file). I don't think it has anything to do with it.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have `SESSION_DOMAIN` in your `.env`? Or did you manually insert domain name in `config/session.php`? Maybe that's the issue.

Comment: @Tajgeer I did not set that, also not in production, and the cookie works in prod.